# Is it possible to upload ZWO file on Android?

Tags: android

Zwift Workout file (*.zwo) can be manually added to custom workouts on PC, Mac and iOS. It is as simple as copying file to a specific folder (e.g. /Documents/Zwift/Workouts). But where is the location for Android Zwift app it picks up local custom workouts from?

Comment: This may be one for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ where you might get an app recommendation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately workout files are not accessible on Android but there is a way you can get them onto your Android device.

To get a custom workout into the Android app you will need to import the workout into Zwift using your PC, Mac or iOS device. This will save the workout on Zwift's servers which in turn will make it accessible in your Android app.

Comment: Mike Poole, this is what I ended up doing, thank you.